# EIP-2771: Is it possible to pay a function with from's eth, not the forwarder contract's eth

Tags: ethers.js, openzeppelin-contracts, meta-transactions

I use OpenZeppelin ERC-2771 lib. I managed to forward an EIP-712 signed transaction to a contract. The function I call is `payable`. So far I only managed to have my Forwarder contract paying the function, instead I would like to have the `from` address paying for the function (but not for the gas; hence a meta-transaction). I know I can transfer Eth by signing a transaction and sending it from a provider, but in my case I need to do both: transfer eth to pay the function and call that function from my forwarder, using `from`'s Eth.

Code for my forwarder:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/metatx/MinimalForwarder.sol";

contract Forwarder is MinimalForwarder {
    constructor() {}
}
```

Code for the contract I am calling with a meta-transaction:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/metatx/ERC2771Context.sol";

contract FooBaz is ERC2771Context {
    constructor(address trustedForwarder) ERC2771Context(trustedForwarder) {}

    uint32 private count = 0;

    function inc() external payable {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

Finally, this is my test case using ethers.js:

```
const data = foobaz.interface.encodeFunctionData('inc');

const req = {
  from: owner.address,
  to: foobaz.address,
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther('1'),
  gas: '100000',
  nonce: (await forwarder.getNonce(owner.address)).toString(),
  data,
};

const signature = await owner._signTypedData(domain, types, req); // domain, types according to EIP-2771 docs
expect(await forwarder.verify(req, signature)).to.be.equal(true);
await forwarder.execute(req, signature);
```

Running `execute` calls `inc` as expected. However it decreases the Forwarder's balance, not `from`'s balance. This makes sense if you look at OZ's implementation:

```
function execute(ForwardRequest calldata req, bytes calldata signature)
{
...
  (bool success, bytes memory returndata) =
    req.to.call{gas: req.gas, value: req.value}(
            abi.encodePacked(req.data, req.from)
        );
```

My question: Is there a way to encode the transfer of Eth value into `data` field? Should it be done in two separate transactions?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with native ETH, as you cannot "pull" ETH from another account, and only the account sending a transaction can send ETH.

Even if you use WETH (ETH wrapped as an ERC20 token) this would be tricky as you would require first that sender approves the contract for the token transfer.

Comment: is the same limitation exist with OpenGSN? Can't you forward Eth from signer's account? As two operations maybe? A transaction to send Eth, then a call? But user signs only once...

Comment: you need to perform an Ethereum transaction to transfer ETH. This cannot be done as a meta transaction. So the user needs to sign the Ethereum tx and the Meta Tx. This limitation also exists with OpenGSN. OpenGSN assumes for the most part, that the `from` doesn't own any ETH and therefore is using MetaTxs